# EhCache Jgroups Replication

Tags: ehcache, jgroups

In my sping based project (spring version 4.1.5.FINAL), I'm using ehcache-core version 2.6.10, ehcache-jgroupsreplication versione 1.7 and jgroups 3.1.0.FINAL

This is my XML ehcache configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd" name="webCache" >
<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir/webCache"/>
<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jgroups.JGroupsCacheManagerPeerProviderFactory" properties="udp.xml"/>
<cache name="it.test.cache.CustomCache"
            maxElementsInMemory="1000"
            eternal="false"
            timeToIdleSeconds="600"
            timeToLiveSeconds="6000"
            overflowToDisk="true">
<cacheEventListenerFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jgroups.JGroupsCacheReplicatorFactory" properties="replicateAsynchronously=true,replicatePuts=true,replicateUpdates=true,replicateUpdatesViaCopy=false,replicateRemovals=true" />
</cache>  
</ehcache>
```

This is my upd.xml configuration:

```
<config xmlns="urn:org:jgroups"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:jgroups http://www.jgroups.org/schema/jgroups.xsd">
    <UDP
         mcast_port="${jgroups.udp.mcast_port:45588}"
         tos="8"
         ucast_recv_buf_size="200K"
         ucast_send_buf_size="200K"
         mcast_recv_buf_size="200K"
         mcast_send_buf_size="200K"
         max_bundle_size="64K"
         max_bundle_timeout="30"
         ip_ttl="${jgroups.udp.ip_ttl:2}"
         enable_diagnostics="true"
         thread_naming_pattern="cl"
         timer_type="new"
         timer.min_threads="4"
         timer.max_threads="10"
         timer.keep_alive_time="3000"
         timer.queue_max_size="500"
         thread_pool.enabled="true"
         thread_pool.min_threads="2"
         thread_pool.max_threads="8"
         thread_pool.keep_alive_time="5000"
         thread_pool.queue_enabled="true"
         thread_pool.queue_max_size="10000"
         thread_pool.rejection_policy="discard"
         oob_thread_pool.enabled="true"
         oob_thread_pool.min_threads="1"
         oob_thread_pool.max_threads="8"
         oob_thread_pool.keep_alive_time="5000"
         oob_thread_pool.queue_enabled="false"
         oob_thread_pool.queue_max_size="100"
         oob_thread_pool.rejection_policy="Run"/>
    <PING />
    <MERGE3 max_interval="30000"
            min_interval="10000"/>
    <FD_SOCK/>
    <FD_ALL/>
    <VERIFY_SUSPECT timeout="1500"  />
    <BARRIER />
    <pbcast.NAKACK use_mcast_xmit="true"
                   retransmit_timeout="300,600,1200"
                   discard_delivered_msgs="true"/>
    <UNICAST/>
    <pbcast.STABLE stability_delay="1000" desired_avg_gossip="50000"
                   max_bytes="4M"/>
    <pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="true" join_timeout="3000"
                view_bundling="true"/>
    <UFC max_credits="2M"
         min_threshold="0.4"/>
    <MFC max_credits="2M"
         min_threshold="0.4"/>
    <FRAG2 frag_size="60K"  />
    <pbcast.STATE_TRANSFER />
</config>
```

In my spring xml context I have the following (I'll put just a fragment of my spring context file):

```
<bean id="settaSystemProps" name="settaSystemProps" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject">
        <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
            <property name="targetClass" value="java.lang.System" />
            <property name="targetMethod" value="getProperties" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property
        name="targetMethod" value="putAll" />
    <property
        name="arguments">
        <util:properties>
            <prop key="jgroups.logging.log_factory_class">it.test.cache.replication.jgroups.log.logback.impl.LogbackLogImpl</prop>
            <prop key="java.net.preferIPv4Stack">true</prop>
        </util:properties>
    </property>
</bean> 
<bean id="webCacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" depends-on="settaSystemProps">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:webCoMiEhCacheCfg.xml"/>
</bean>
```

Sadly, by using this configuration, I'm not able in sending/receiving messages in the cluster

When I start my tomcat I see the following print (and it's not using my custom log):

> feb 27, 2015 10:31:18 AM org.jgroups.logging.JDKLogImpl error Grave:
>   failed sending message to cluster (65 bytes): java.lang.Exception:
>   dest=/228.8.8.8:45588 (68 bytes), cause: java.io.IOException: Invalid
>   argument 
>   feb 27, 2015 10:31:19 AM org.jgroups.logging.JDKLogImpl error
>   Grave: failed sending message to cluster (65 bytes):
>   java.lang.Exception: dest=/228.8.8.8:45588 (68 bytes), cause:
>   java.io.IOException: Invalid argument 
>   feb 27, 2015 10:31:28 AM
>   org.jgroups.logging.JDKLogImpl error Grave: failed sending message to
>   cluster (65 bytes): java.lang.Exception: dest=/228.8.8.8:45588 (68
>   bytes), cause: java.io.IOException: Invalid argument feb 27, 2015
>   10:31:28 AM org.jgroups.logging.JDKLogImpl error Grave: failed sending
>   message to cluster (65 bytes): java.lang.Exception:
>   dest=/228.8.8.8:45588 (68 bytes), cause: java.io.IOException: Invalid
>   argument

Can anybody tell me where I'm wrong? What I need is to synchronize EhCache on a cluster formed by 2 nodes

Can anybody provide to me a working configuration sample?

thank you

Angelo

Answer (score 1):

What's the output when you start an instance ? I think you might still be using IPv6. Can you use -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true instead of defining this in the XML ?

Comment: I tried as you suggested and now it seems to be working; in my environment i set the following properties: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djgroups.logging.log_factory_class=customLog. Caches are now synchronized on a cluster formed by 3 nodes (2 tomcat and 1 IBM WAS) but it seems to me that customLog is not used. In any case...thank you

Comment: You probably need to define the full classname of the custom log. Glad to hear it works now

Comment: i used the full qualified name (in the early comment i used a shortcut) I'll try to investigate because i need to use logback implementation of the logger...thank you

Comment: @Angelo. Custom logger is not working for me either. have you been able to solve the problem?